# Nested ForkJoin doesn't run in Parent ForkJoin

Tags: rxjs, reactive

I'm working with RxJS. So I meet the problem with child forkjoin(). if you have any experience on this. please give me your idea

I see that the parent forkjoin is finished before the child one

```
getParent(url,id){
   return this.http.get(url + 'id'})
            .flatMap(reports => {
                return Observable.combineLatest(
                    reports.map(report => {
                        return Observable.forkJoin(
                           getChilds(url,report.ids)
                        ).map(data => {
                           //do something
                        })
                     })
           )
       })
}

getChilds(url,list){
   return Observable.forkJoin<Specimen>(
            list.forEach(specimen => {
                this.htt.get(url + 'specimen.reference').map(spec => {
                    //Do somthing

                })
            })
        )
}
```

Thanks
Nam

Comment: The `forkJoin()` operator takes as a parameter an array of Observables and you don't `return` anything from `list.forEach`'s callback.

Comment: It works perfectly. thanks Martin so much